# Linearizing max constraint Problem

Tags: modeling, integer-programming, constraint, binary-variable, logical-constraints

I want to linearize a max constraint as below:
[image]

In which x_(i,t),are binary decision variables and T is a constant.

How can I linearize this constraint?

Comment: I do think this is essentially a duplicate of the question that @dhasson linked to, so I'm going to close it. If I'm wrong, please either comment here and explain why it should be reopened, or just ask a new question with more details.

Comment: Also, in the future, please use [MathJax](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/38) to format both optimization models and math in your questions. Thanks, and welcome to OR.SE!